# Are "can" and "could" interchangeable in a sentence

Tags: modal-verbs

> 1. He is so hungry that he could eat a horse.
> 2. He is so hungry that he can eat a horse.

I want to know if I can interchange the idiom "could eat a horse" to "can eat a horse".

Comment: Using the past form (could) creates a distance from reality. So, *could* expresses something that is more unlikely to be true.

Comment: @user178049 - Yes, or is less likely to happen. The original version reads like hyperbole – we understand that the person is unlikely to eat any part of a horse, much less an entire horse. The modified version creates an impression that the speaker is being more serious. I'd expect that usage in a sentence like: _He gets so hungry he can eat an entire pizza_.